# ASL Hand Gesture Recognition using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, gesture, gesture-recognition

we are making an ASL Hand Gesture Recognition program in C++ using OpenCV. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Sign_Language (ASL). here's a list of the different hand gestures: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:ABC_pict.png

i have read about cvConvexityDefects() and i think it can handle hands that have finger/s open.

how do i handle the hand gestures that have finger/s closed like A, E, M, N, S, and T?
how about the moving hand gestures like J and Z?

Answer (score 0):

This is a terribly difficult research problem on which many people are currently working. You won't be able to tackle it just by using OpenCv, this will require more work.

If you want to model finger occlusions, you will need to introduce a prior model of your hand and finger joints. Google for related works.

Comment: so what do you think would be the best approach for this research problem?